# Can't login to domain

Tags: domain, active-directory, login

I have a group of machines that are all plugged into the same switch and all but one machine is able to log in to the domain. I get the following message:

```
there are currently no logon servers available to service the logon request
```

I've tried restarting and have had others try to log in and they get the same message. I don't understand why one machine would be giving me this message while the others have no issue.

Answer (score 5):

This means that that machine cannot find a domain controller on the network. Log in locally and check the following:

1) You actually have network connectivity

2) That machine is set to use AD DNS and not some other DNS provider

3) You can ping the DCs

4) This machine is joined to the correct domain (if you have multiple domains/forests)

5) That the port on the switch isn't bad.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the DNS settings on the problematic client to ensure it is pointing to the AD DNS.